# will keeping same version of jar in ear lib and war lib creates issue?

Tags: java, jar, jboss, ejb, classloader

I am keeping of same version of jar inside war/lib and ear/lib.

Could you please let me know whether this will create any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Better to have your common libs in EAR/lib , since Web module can access the JARs on EAR/lib. Also another option to have your common libraries in you application server ext/lib folder but then you have to separately send those when releasing EAR which is also not a good practice.

```
BIG.ear
 +-- lib (contains common libs for all modules)
 +-- META-INF
 |    +-- application.xml (lists modules myWEB.war and myEJB.jar)
 |    +-- MANIFEST.MF
 +-- myEJB.jar
 |    +-- META-INF
 |    |    +- ejb-jar.xml
 |    
 |         +-- ...
 +-- myWEB.war
      +-- META-INF
      |    +-- MANIFEST.MF 
      +-- WEB-INF
      |    |+-- lib (3rd party libs only used by .war)
      |    +-- web.xml
      +-- index.html
```

Comment: My confusion is I just want to know what will happen if I keep two copy of same jar. Will it creates any issues with respect to class loader.

Comment: Well, there is no conflict as long as both libraries having same JARs, to  more explain class loading in general.  In the delegation design, a class loader delegates class loading to its parent before attempting to load a class itself. A class loader parent can be either the System class loader or custom class loader. If the parent class loader cannot load a class, 
the class loader attempts to load the class itself. In effect, a class loader is responsible for loading only the classes not available to the parent.So your child is WAR and Parent is EAR here, so your Web will use EARs Jar files.